# unable to center my images when resizing window with next.js

Tags: image, next.js, responsive, nextjs-image

I'm using Next.js and the `Image` component. My problem is when I resize the window my image does not stay centered.

I've tried margin auto, display `flex` with `justify-content` and align content centered, object-fit and object position.

I also tried every layout options for the `Image` component.

The top of the image gets crop when I resize to a bigger window or the height stays the same but the width becomes wider so that proportions does not stay.

(I simplified the code to the images)

```js
<section className={styles.click}>
  <div className="container">
    <h2>Clique, trouve, bouge</h2>
    <p>
      Tu veux te dépenser, faire une activité de relaxation ou juste aller
      marcher. Bouge cartographie pour toi tous les spots publics, les
      associations, les studios privés et les activités de groupe dans ta ville.
    </p>
    <div className={styles.pictures}>
      <div className={styles.img}>
        <Image src="/images/city.jpg" alt="" width={500} height={500} />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.img}>
        <Image src="/images/climbing.jpg" alt="" width={500} height={500} />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.img}>
        <Image src="/images/karate.jpg" alt="" width={500} height={500} />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.img}>
        <Image src="/images/beach.jpg" alt="" width={500} height={500} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```css
 .click .pictures {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  }

  .img {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    border-radius: 23px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
.pictures {
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  border-radius: 23px;
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-sun-smwow

Comment: Note quite.The images stay centered but my images must have the same dimensions and the ratio must stay with the responsive. Like, if they are square, they must stay square.
And adding your code does not resolve my problem.

Comment: @FlorieAnstett I only used different dimensions as an example. Check the sandbox again. I made all the images squares.

Comment: Indeed. I don't know why it isn't working for my app. If I apply this code, the image's width becomes very thin but the height stays.